# How can i change the texts of plugin (created by me) in wordpress admin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-qtranslate

i have a created a contact us plugin, i want to change that name of the plugin "contact us" in Hindi. I already created languages folder in my wordpress, and maintaining hi_IN.mo, hi_IN.po files.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Answer (score 0):

i have added keywords of my plugin to hi_IN.po file and generated .mo file. Finally i found text what i added is in hindi language. and in my plugin i displayed those texts with the help of function  __().

```
 ex:-  __("Read More")
```